# $\underset{K}{\text{minimize}} ( (K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T)^\intercal ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T)$ with equality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus

I would like to solve the following function.

\begin{align}
&\underset{K}{\text{minimize}} & ( (K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T)^\intercal ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T)\\
&\text{s.t}& K^\intercal \mathbf{1}_n = \mathbf{1}_m
\end{align}

Where $\circ$ is the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), $K, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $T \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $^\intercal$ is the transposed of the matrix and $\mathbf{1}_n, \mathbf{1}_m$ are vectors of ones of size $n$ and $m$ respectively.

Thus, I tried but I got stuck pretty quickly. So, first I set my lagrange multiplier function ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {L}}(x,\lambda )=f(x)-\lambda g(x)}$. Thus:

$$
( (K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T)^\intercal ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m - T) - \lambda^\intercal(K^\intercal\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{1}_m)\\
$$

Where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I try then to develop the equation:

$$
\mathcal {L}=((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m)^\intercal((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m)- ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m)^\intercal T - T ^\intercal ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m) + T^\intercal T - \lambda^\intercal(K^\intercal\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{1}_m)
$$

$$
\mathcal {L}=\mathbf{1}_m^\intercal (K\circ P)^\intercal(K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m- \mathbf{1}_m^\intercal (K\circ P)^\intercal T - T ^\intercal ((K\circ P)\mathbf{1}_m) + T^\intercal T - \lambda^\intercal(K^\intercal\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{1}_m)
$$

From here I have questions because I do not know if I have some properties as for example in $(K\circ P)^\intercal(K\circ P)$ with the hadamard product. Anyway, if I follow with the derivatives, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}$ is easy:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} =K^\intercal \mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{1}_m
$$

However, concerning $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial K}$ I do not know how to proceed since $K$ is a matrix. I know for sure that I can drop the term $T^\intercal T$, but besides that I'm kind of lost.

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial K} = ?
$$

I looked into the [matrix cookbook](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ewelling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) and [here](https://dawenl.github.io/files/mat_deriv.pdf) for some insight. I should be able to use some property such as $\nabla_A XAY = X^\intercal Y^\intercal$, however I'm still stuck, mainly I would not know how to combine that property with $(K\circ P)^\intercal(K\circ P)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\o{{\large\tt1}}\def\R#1{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Let
$(\odot,\oslash)$ denote element-wise multiplication and division. Then, instead
of a building a Lagragian, you can use the all-ones matrix $J\in\R{n\times n}$ and an unconstrained matrix $U\in\R{n\times m}$ to satisfy the constraint by constructing
$$\eqalign{
K &= U\oslash JU \quad\implies\quad K^T\o_n = \o_m \\
}$$
It will also be convenient to define some auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign{
a &= \left(P\odot K\right)\o_m - T \\
A &= \D(a) \\
F &= 2P\odot (a\o_m^T) = 2AP \\
b &= U^T\o_n \\
B &= \D(b) \\
C &= B^{-1} \\
v &= \d\left(U^TFC^2\right) \\
}$$
Write the objective function in terms these new variables.

Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= a:a \\
d\phi &= 2a:da \\
  &= 2a:\left(P\odot dK\right)\o_m \\
  &= F:dK \\
  &= F:\left(dU\oslash JU\right) - F:(U\odot J\,dU \oslash JU\oslash JU) \\
  &= \left(F\oslash JU\right):dU - (F\oslash JU\oslash JU):(U\odot J\,dU) \\
  &= FC:dU - FC^2:U\,dB \\
  &= FC:dU - U^TFC^2:\D\left(dU^T\o_n\right) \\
  &= FC:dU - v\o_n^T:dU^T \\
  &= \Big(FC - \o_nv^T\Big):dU \\
\p{\phi}{U} &= \Big(FC - \o_nv^T\Big) \;\doteq\; G \\\\
}$$
Knowing the gradient, we can use gradient descent to solve for the optimal $U.$
$$\eqalign{
i &= 0 \\
U_0 &= \o_n\o_m \qquad\qquad \big({\rm initialize}\big) \\
\\
K_i &= U_i\oslash JU_i  \qquad\; \big({\rm current\,solution}\big)  \\
F_i &= 2\;\D\Big(\big(P\odot K_i\big)\o_m - T\Big) P \\
C_i &= \D\big(U_i^T\o_n\big)^{-1} \\
v_i &= \d\big(U_i^TF_iC_i^2\big) \\
G_i &= F_iC_i - \o_nv_i^T \\
U_{i+1} &= U_i - \lambda_i G_i \\
i &= i+{\tt1} \qquad\qquad \big({\rm next\,iteration}\big) \\
}$$
The steplength $\lambda_i>0$ is chosen to minimize (or sufficiently reduce) $\phi$ for the current step.

Instead of gradient descent, it might be possible to solve $(G=0)$ directly with some clever algebra, however the equation is highly nonlinear.

---

In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}\big(A^TB\big)
  \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
${\bf NB\!:}\;{\rm If}\;m={\tt1},\,{\rm then}\,(A,B)$ are vectors and this
corresponds to the standard dot product.

Comment: best answers to matrix derivative questions are always provided by greg!

Comment: thanks @greg for your answer, it seems like a pretty complete answer, but I'll need some time to check it due to my lack of background in Matrix Calculus (sorry for that). All the $Tr$, $Diag$ and other functions seem still like black magic to me. I'll come in some days with more background before saying something nonsense to you =)

Comment: @greg I'm deeply sorry It took me a year to come back. In the end, my problem became something else (I don't remember what exactly). I checked your procedure, seems accurate. I would have to code it to check if it converges. If at some point I have time to play around with it, I'll let you know. Thanks.